# SharePoint online list get value lookup field with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I'm quite new with both SharePoint and PowerShell so please bear with me. I created a list on SharePoint and I'm trying to get the values of items in this list. For the most part this works ok except for the lookup fields. Whenever I tried to read the values of those fields I get the following value:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue
```

This is the code I use:

```
foreach ($item in $Items) {
$ListItem = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem]$listItem = $List.GetItemById($Item.FieldValues["ID"])
$SPListItemColumns = @{
    Department = "Department"
    }
$Department = $item.FieldValues[$SPListItemColumns.Department] 
}
```

I tried the code found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20831.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-powershell.aspx#Set_and_Get_a_Lookup_Field), but this returns the following error: `Unable to find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue].`

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code to fetch the lookup field values from a list items.

```
foreach ($listitem in $listItems)  
{
    $lookup = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue]$listitem.FieldValues["lookup column name"]
    write-host "lookupValue - $($lookup.LookupValue)"
    write-host "lookupId - $($lookup.LookupId)"
}
```